# Filtering out the most popular name for males and females each year (babynames dataset, R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am fairly new to R and I currently trying out dplyr with the babynames dataset. So far everything is working perfectly fine, however I cant think of any function/code that would extract me the most popular name for each year from the dataset.

If anybody could show me such a function or point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you provide a portion of the dataset you are using ? and also the code you have try so far ? (please check how to add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

Comment: Apparently, `babynames` is a [CRAN package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/babynames/).

Answer (score 3):

If you want the most popular name regardless of the sex, then you can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
most_popular <- babynames %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    top_n(1, wt=n)
```

Comment: `library(dplyr)
library(babynames)

male_tops <- babynames %>% 
  filter(sex=="M") %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  top_n(1, wt=n)

female_tops <- babynames %>% 
  filter(sex=="F") %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  top_n(1, wt=n)

total <- rbind(male_tops, female_tops)`

this is what i have so far. 
Is there a way by which i can combine two dataframes a row wise, and not the whole dataframe at once?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, but you can achieve the same result a bit more succinctly like this: `library(dplyr)
library(babynames)
library(tidyr)
most_popular <- babynames %>% 
 group_by(year, sex) %>% 
 top_n(1, wt=n)` and if you would like a more "wide" format like this: `library(dplyr)
library(babynames)
library(tidyr)
most_popular <- babynames %>% 
 group_by(year, sex) %>% 
 top_n(1, wt=n) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = c(sex), values_from = c(n, name, prop))`